# Building array from string values

Tags: php

I have a table that has a column with data stored as comma-separated strings.

I need to output the table contents and build an array from these values (don't need any keys).

I need to remove duplicates and sort it in alphabetical order.

```
$arr = array();

foreach ($myTable AS $t) {
    $str = $t->myStr;
    array_push($arr, $str);
} 

array_unique($arr);
asort($arr);
```

I did print_r($arr); Now I see values but they are still an array of strings. Something like this:

> Array ( [1] => Chinese, Asian Fusion, Food Trucks [0] => Chinese,
>   Asian Fusion, Gluten-Free [2] => Chinese, Barbeque [3] => Dim Sum,
>   Seafood, Soup )

What I would like to see is:

> Array ('Asian Fusion', 'Barbeque', 'Chinese', 'Food Trucks',
>   'Gluten-Free'...);

Comment: 1) Please add a little example with some data what you have and in which form do you want to get it? (multidimensional array, one dimensional array, ...) 2) `array_unique()` should be reassigned to `$arr`

Comment: Besides from @Rizier123's comment on [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), there is no attempt to output anything in your code. Please, take a look at  [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php): use it like so `print_r($arr);`

Comment: updated original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change this line:

```
array_push( $arr, $str );
```

in:

```
$arr = array_merge( $arr, explode( ',', $str) );
```

and this:

```
array_unique( $arr );
```

in:

```
$arr = array_unique( $arr );
```

`array_push()` add the comma-separated string to the array. Using `explode()` you obtain an array with single values, then you have to merge this array with main array. You can't use `array_push()` with exploded array, because using it you will obtain a multidimensional array ( [ [Chinese,Asian,...] , [Chinese,Asian,...] ] ).

`array_unique()` doesn't change the original array, but it return the modified array, so you have to catch the result in a variable.

#### Edit:

The delimiter must be the **complete** separation string.
So, if your string is like this:

> ```
> Chinese, Asian Fusion, Food Trucks
>         ^             ^
> ```

you have to use:

```
$arr = array_merge( $arr, explode( ', ', $str) );
//                                   ^
```

Comment: `explode(', ', ...` since it looks like there is also a space in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array();

foreach ($myTable AS $t) {
    $str = $t->myStr;
    $arr = array_merge($arr, explode(', ', $str))
} 

$arr = array_unique($arr);
asort($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: use explode for extract separated data from string

Comment: `explode(', ', ...` since it looks like there is also a space in there.